# Magento 2: Ui Component - Magento\Customer\Model\Session can't return current customer

Tags: magento2, collection, uicomponent, model, virtualtype

I've got an issue using ui component on front in a large module.
The model I'm using for my grid is used at several other points.
But I discovered my configuration in di.xml is doing some strange things.

```
<virtualType name="VENDOR\MODULE\Model\ResourceModel\ModelName\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_modelname</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">VENDOR\MODULE\Model\ResourceModel\ModelName</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Then when I'm using the factory to create my collection, as following

```
public function __construct(
    \VENDOR\MODULE\Model\ModelName $modelFactory
)
{
    $this->modelFactory= $modelFactory;
}

 public function execute()
 {
    $this->modelFactory->create();
```

I've got the following error :

```
Type Error occurred when creating object:
```

In the logs I have more infos

```
 Type Error occurred when creating object: VENDOR\MODULE\Model\ModelName, Argument 4 passed to VENDOR\MODULE\Model\ModelName::__construct() must be an instance of VENDOR\MODULE\Model\ResourceModel\ModelName\Collection, instance of Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult given, called in /var/www/project/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 117 [] []
```

When I delete the virtual type, my model can be used with no problem. But the UI component crash.

Do you have any idea how to resolve that problem ?
I couldn't find any existing subject linked to this problem but if you find any... Let me know !
Thank you ;)

**EDIT :**
There is the code of my model **VENDOR/MODULE/Model/ModelName**

```
<?php

namespace VENDOR\MODULE\Model;

use VENDOR\MODULE\Api\Data\ModelInterface;
use VENDOR\MODULE\Api\Data\ModelInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper;

class ModelName extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{

    protected $modelDataFactory;

    protected $dataObjectHelper;

    protected $_eventPrefix = 'vendor_mymodel_name';

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param ModelInterfaceFactory $modelDataFactory
     * @param DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper
     * @param \VENDOR\MODULE\Model\ResourceModel\ModelName $resource
     * @param \VENDOR\MODULE\Model\ResourceModel\ModelName\Collection $resourceCollection
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \VENDOR\MODULE\Model\ResourceModel\ModelName $resource,
        \VENDOR\MODULE\Model\ResourceModel\ModelName\Collection $resourceCollection,
        \VENDOR\MODULE\Api\Data\ModelName InterfaceFactory $modelDataFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->modelDataFactory = $modelDataFactory;
        $this->dataObjectHelper = $dataObjectHelper;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve model with data
     * @return ModelNameInterface
     */
    public function getDataModel()
    {
        $modelData = $this->getData();

        $modelDataObject = $this->modelDataFactory->create();
        $this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
            $modeDataObject,
            $modelData,
            ModelInterface::class
        );

        return $modelDataObject;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2 :**
I've tryed some more things, unsuccessfully for the moment.
As I couldn't get the user Id in the model, for any reason, I tried to get it from a helper. No more success.

I finnally tried with a DataProvider (**Ui/DataProvider/DataProvider.php**), that I saw in negotiableQuote. No more Success...

```
<?php

namespace VENDOR\MODULE\Ui\DataProvider;

use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Reporting;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchResultsInterface;
/**
 * Class DataProvider
 * @package VENDOR\MODULE\Ui\DataProvider
 */
class DataProvider extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider
{

    /**
     * @var \VENDOR\MODULE\Model\ModelNameRepository
     */
    private $ModelNameRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Authorization\Model\UserContextInterface
     */
    private $userContext;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Company\Model\Company\Structure
     */
    private $structure;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Company\Api\AuthorizationInterface
     */
    private $authorization;

    /**
     * DataProvider constructor.
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param Reporting $reporting
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @param FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
     * @param \VENDOR\MODULE\Model\ModelNameRepository $ModelNameRepository
     * @param \Magento\Authorization\Model\UserContextInterface $userContext
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Company\Model\Company\Structure $structure
     * @param \Magento\Company\Api\AuthorizationInterface $authorization
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        Reporting $reporting,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        \VENDOR\MODULE\Model\ModelNameRepository $ModelNameRepository,
        \Magento\Authorization\Model\UserContextInterface $userContext,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Company\Model\Company\Structure $structure,
        \Magento\Company\Api\AuthorizationInterface $authorization,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $name,
            $primaryFieldName,
            $requestFieldName,
            $reporting,
            $searchCriteriaBuilder,
            $request,
            $filterBuilder,
            $meta,
            $data
        );
        $this->ModelNameRepository = $ModelNameRepository;
        $this->userContext = $userContext;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->structure = $structure;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->authorization = $authorization;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        return $this->formatOutput($this->getSearchResult());
    }

    /**
     * Returns Search result.
     *
     * @return SearchResultsInterface
     */
    public function getSearchResult()
    {
        $this->addOrder('entity_id', 'DESC');
        $customerId = $this->getCustomerId();
        var_dump($customerId);
        $filter = $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField('main_table.company_id')
            ->setConditionType('eq')
            ->setValue($customerId)
            ->create();
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter($filter);
        $this->searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
        $this->searchCriteria->setRequestName($this->name);

        return $this->ModelNameRepository->getList($this->getSearchCriteria(), true);
    }

    /**
     * @return int|null
     */
    private function getCustomerId()
    {
        return $this->userContext->getUserId() ?  : null;
    }

    /**
     * @param SearchResultsInterface $searchResult
     * @return array
     */
    private function formatOutput(SearchResultsInterface $searchResult)
    {
        $arrItems = [];
        $arrItems['totalRecords'] = $searchResult->getTotalCount();

        $arrItems['items'] = [];
        foreach ($searchResult->getItems() as $item) {
            $itemData = [];
            foreach ($item->getData() as $key => $value) {
                $itemData[$key] = $value;
            }
            $arrItems['items'][] = $itemData;
        }
        return $arrItems;
    }
```

and there is my new di.xml (I left the comments of the old try)

```
<virtualType name="Naval\MyOffers\Model\ResourceModel\Offers\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">naval_myoffers_offers</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Naval\MyOffers\Model\ResourceModel\Offers\Collection</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<!--<type name="Naval\MyOffers\Model\ResourceModel\Offers\Grid\Collection">-->
    <!--<arguments>-->
        <!--<argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">naval_myoffers_offers</argument>-->
        <!--<argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Naval\MyOffers\Model\ResourceModel\Offers</argument>-->
    <!--</arguments>-->
<!--</type>-->
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="naval_myoffers_offers_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Naval\MyOffers\Model\ResourceModel\Offers\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

** EDIT 3 : The situation Changed yesterday.  **
 It's working again as I'm using the data provider (See Edit 2), but the customer session does not work anymore.  I cannot get the customer Id to filter in my DataProvider.

Comment: I think you just need to run command "setup:di:compile".

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but no, I already tried it several times, and once again just now. It has no effect on that "bug".

Comment: Can you please provide code of your model (VENDOR\MODULE\Model\ModelName)?

Comment: Post Edited, I added my model

Comment: try deleting generated folder manually and rerun ..

Comment: I'm usually running this : rm -rf generated/code/* generated/metadata/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/cache/* (no success. Am I missing a file to delete ?)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your di.xml as follows, i have added **Grid** before collection. But no need to create a Grid folder place the collection file as usual in

**VENDOR/MODULE/Model/ResourceModel/ModelName/Collection**

```
<virtualType name="VENDOR\MODULE\Model\ResourceModel\ModelName\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_modelname</argument>
        <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">module_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">VENDOR\MODULE\Model\ResourceModel\ModelName</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

To get Customer id,

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
}
```

Comment: That is what I have already. I Initially created the Grid/Collection class and add a filter in the _beforeLoad method. But the /Magento\Customer\Model\Session->getCustomer->getId() returned null. Now I have the same VirtualType as you suggested me, with the data provider. (I filter in the dataProvider.) But still no successfull result.

Comment: could you update the code with the changes..

Comment: I updated it and added the new di.xml, thank you for your return

Comment: I have updated my answer..

Comment: Magento\Customer\Model\Session->getCustomer()->getId() is still returning null, even with the changes you proposed...

Comment: have you checked customer isLoggedIn() ?

Comment: From the controller, isLoggedIn() returns true, but from the dataProvider, it returns false... And this website requires a connected customer to be able the browse it, no stranger are allowed. (I'm sorry, the initial question did changed pretty much)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98350/discussion-between-aravind-and-mric).